# Compact and convex discrete set

Tags: convex-analysis, compactness

I am working with discrete sets but I have a doubt: is the set $\{ 0,1\}$ compact and convex?
And the set $\{ 0,1\}^2=\{(0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (1,1) \}$?

Comment: No, they are not.

Comment: They are neither compact and convex? Can you explain more?

Comment: Well, every finite set is compact. To show they are not convex, you just have to find a convex combination of elements in the set which does not lie in the set. Every nondegenerate convex combination will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\left \{0,1\right \}$ is not convex, because based on defintion $\lambda*0+(1-\lambda)*1 \notin \left \{0,1\right \}$.